# How to join multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to list producers information who produce CD of a particular artist released in a particular year.

My attempt:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM producer, cd WHERE name = name and year= year JOIN SELECT * FROM cd, song WHERE  artist = '$_POST[artist]' AND cd.title ='$_POST[title]'"; 
$data=mysqli_query($sql); 
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
print_r($row);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   'JOIN SELECT * FROM cd, song WHERE artist = '' AND cd.title =''' at line 1

How am I joining the two queries incorrectly?

Comment: You have multiple problems with your syntax, using `where` instead of `on`.  No parentheses around a subquery.  And, I cannot follow the logic at all.

Comment: Also, you're so wide open to SQL injection it'll get discovered/exploited by automated tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM producer AS p 
INNER JOIN cd        ON cd.name  = p.name AND cd.year= p.year 
INNER JOIN song AS s ON cd.title = s.title
WHERE s.artist = '$_POST[artist]' 
  AND cd.title ='$_POST[title]';
```

You should put all the referenced tables after the `FROM` clause with the `JOIN` <sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Where the table reference can be <sup>2</sup>:

[image]

To put a `SELECT` or a subquery instead of the table, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM producer AS p 
INNER JOIN 
(
    -- here is another select
) AS analias ON -- jon conditino
WHERE ...
```

---

<sup>1, 2: <sup>Images from: [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433362)</sup></sup>

Comment: The join to `song` is unnecessary and will produce duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the `artist` column come from that table, thats why I put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a bit of reading on general SQL and joins.

The SQL you need will be

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Producer
    INNER JOIN cd
            ON Producer.[name] = cd.[name]

WHERE
    cd.artist = '$_POST[artist]' 
AND cd.title  = '$_POST[title]'

I haven't included table 'song' as I can't see what the join field will be.

I have no idea whether the substitution code for the posted strings is correct: I'm not familiar with PHP. I would strongly recommend that you declare some variables, populate them from $_Post, and pass them into the SQL string with a bit of 'cleaning', as your code looks like an invitation to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score -1):

Why not?

```
SELECT * FROM producer as p, cd, song 
WHERE cd.name=p.name AND cd.year= p.year AND 
      cd.title=song.title AND cd.artist = '$_POST[artist]' AND 
      cd.title = '$_POST[title];
```

Check out the `$_POST` before query may be interesting